# SQL Update statement error

Tags: c#, sql, ms-access, ado.net

What's wrong with this SQL UPDATE statement?

```
try
{
   int ageValue = Int32.Parse(age.Text);

   string updateQuery = "Update \nMyTable \nSet \nFName = '" + fname.Text.ToString() + "',\nLName = '" + lname.Text.ToString() + "',\nAge = " + ageValue + ",\nCome = '" + from.Text.ToString() + "',\nTo = '" + to.Text.ToString() + "' Where Age=" + ageValue + ";";

   MessageBox.Show(updateQuery);

   OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection("provider=Microsoft.JET.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source = Database5.mdb");

   OleDbCommand com = new OleDbCommand(updateQuery, con);

   con.Open();
   com.ExecuteNonQuery();
   con.Close();
}
catch (FormatException ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
catch (OleDbException ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
```

I received that error

> Syntax error in Update statement

What is wrong in that SQL Update?

Tools:

- Microsoft Access 2003
- Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 C#

Please help and thanks in advance

Comment: Post the generated SQL please. Also seriously consider ditching this technique and using a parameterised command object instead.

Comment: Your SQL seems correct, but we can't view table `MyTable` structure. Could you post it?

Comment: `To` is reserved keyword. Put it in brackets.

Comment: What is the error you get? Also, you don't need to call ToString() on Text fields as they are already text. And why are you including newlines in your SQL string?

Comment: remove \n from query. and better if you post the genrated query here.

Comment: I strongly suspect you have two dates in there and the delimiter for dates is hash (#), not quote ('). In addition, beware of locale problems with date. Ensure your date strings are unambiguous. As @Simon said (heh) you could avoid most of these problems with a parameter or two.

Comment: By the way, you are not using Access 2013 with Jet. I guess you mean 2003.

Answer (score 2):

Try getting rid of the \n junk.

```
string updateQuery = "Update MyTable Set FName = '" + fname.Text.ToString() + "',LName = '" + lname.Text.ToString() + "',Age = " + ageValue + ",Come = '" + from.Text.ToString() + "',To = '" + to.Text.ToString() + "' Where Age=" + ageValue;
```

Output the result of the concatination and try to run it.  If that doesn't work, post the result of the concatination here and someone should be able to help.  Without knowing the result of the concatination, it's difficult to know what's wrong.

Comment: hey i used \n only for the readability of the UpdateQuery when i send it to the MessageBox

Comment: I'm not sure if Access can handle line feeds - but the trailing semi-colon is not needed and could be your issue.  Without seeing the final output of the contatination, it will be difficult to know what's really going on.

Answer (score 2):

Try changing the query like this (removing `\n`s and the final `;`)

```
string updateQuery = "Update MyTable Set FName = '" + fname.Text.ToString() + 
    "', LName = '" + lname.Text.ToString() + "', Age = " + ageValue + 
    ", Come = '" + from.Text.ToString() + "', To = '" + to.Text.ToString() + 
    "' Where Age=" + ageValue;
```

Comment: If you have to piece the SQL together in a string then I would recommend using String.Format().

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you put the Sql Profiler on and trace your update query because it is easy to read the concatenated query string

Answer (score 0):

Hello you can try with this code

```
StringBuilder  stringBuilder = new StringBuilder() ;
stringBuilder.Append("Update MyTable Set FName = ") ;
stringBuilder.Append(fname.Text.ToString()) ;
stringBuilder.Append(",\nLName = ") ;
stringBuilder.Append(lname.Text.ToString()) ;
stringBuilder.Append(",\nAge = ") ;
stringBuilder.Append(ageValue) ;

stringBuilder.Append(",\nCome = ") ;
stringBuilder.Append(from.Text.ToString()) ;
stringBuilder.Append(",\nTo = ") ;
stringBuilder.Append(to.Text.ToString()) ;

stringBuilder.Append(" Where Age=") ;
stringBuilder.Append(ageValue) ;
stringBuilder.Append(";") ;


var result = stringBuilder.ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I write my inline SQL in C sharp:

```
string strSQL = "";
strSQL += "  Update MyTable Set  ";
strSQL += "  FName =  '" + fname.Text.ToString() + "'  ";
strSQL += "  ,LName = '" + lname.Text.ToString() + "'  ";
strSQL += "  ,Age =   '" + ageValue              + "'  ";
strSQL += "  ,Come =  '" + from.Text.ToString()  + "'  ";
strSQL += "  ,To =    '" + to.Text.ToString()    + "'  ";
strSQL += "  Where Age = '" + ageValue + "'  ";
```

Easy to read and works fine.

You can also add this just below your query before you connent to your database:

```
Response.Write(strSQL);
return;
```

this will show you whats being posted to the server and makes it a little easier to find errors.